# how to get flexible three column layout in Boostrap?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am working on setting up a Asp.Net Master page that uses Bootstrap. We have a three column layout with third column as optional

```
<div class="row " >
    <div id="leftCol" class="col-sm-3 no-left-gutter  leftmenu" />
    <div class="col-sm-7" id="centercol' />
    <div class="col-sm-2" id = "rightcol"> <asp:ContentPlaceHolder .../>  </div><div>
```

Now If any of the pages inheriting this master page ***doesn't use*** the rightCol div to place any content then the right column should be hidden and the center column should take size of both center and right column.

Is there any way to achieve this easily using bootstrap (or with out it)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The class for the centercol and rightcol divs can be set dynamically based on right column's visibility

visible:  class set to col-sm-7(center) and col-sm-2 (right)

hidden : class set to col-sma-9(center) and display:none (right)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `ContentPlaceHolder` for any content and set the `CssClass` in code behind:

ASPX:

```
<div class="row " >
    <div id="leftCol" class="col-sm-3 no-left-gutter leftmenu" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pCenter" runat="server"> 
    <asp:Panel ID="pRight" runat="server"> 
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphRight" runat="server" />
    </div>
<div>
```

CS:

```
if(this.cphRight.Controls.Count > 0) 
{
    this.pCenter.CssClass = "col-sm-7";
    this.pRight.CssClass = "col-sm-2";
}
else
{
    this.pCenter.CssClass = "col-sm-9";
    this.pRight.Visible = false;
}
```

I used `asp:Panel` instead of `div`, because they come handy and generate a `div`, too. Alternatively, you can still use a `div` but you should give it the attribute and value `runat="server"` to be able to access it in code behind.